# how to implement findFragmentById in onBackPressed to find HomeFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working with fragments in navigation drawer layout. I want to return to HomeFragment on pressing back button each time when any other fragment is visible in frame_container. and if home fragment is already visible i want to finish MainActivity (navigation_drawer_activity). Help me correct this code of OnBackPressed in main activity.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_home);
    if(fragment!=null && fragment.isVisible()){
        clearBackStack();
        finish();
    }else {
        clearBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you used ViewPager to manage your fregment ?

Comment: No am using frame layout..

Comment: And fragment manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. I found the fragment from `frame_container`. 
and then checked in if statement.  `if(fragment!=null && fragment instanceof HomeFragment && fragment.isVisible())`. this returned `home_fragment`. 
Thanks for your answers.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    if(fragment!=null && fragment instanceof HomeFragment && fragment.isVisible()){
        clearBackStack();
        finish();
    }else {
        clearBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this returned current fragment. and finished the activity each time i pressed back.

Comment: have you used addToBackStack while replacing the fragments?

Comment: actually i dont want to iterate through whole backstack on pressing back. i just want to go directly to home fragment.